# Wired Access Point Has only half Wireless Speed

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wired-networking, wired

We moved to a new apartment where the WAN port to the furthest corner of the place so now in my bedroom I am unable to connect to WiFi.

I decided to connect a wired Access Point but my problem is that the WiFi in the bedroom should be 50 Mbps but it is only around 22Mbps ...when I plug a network cable into the AP speed is 50Mbps as expected so I am not sure what's the issue here.

First I tried Access Point :  **EDIMAX EW-7206PDg** which only supports 1 cable to main router and then only WiFi but speed was the same. I figured it's because it has only G broadband so..

My second option was :**ZyXel VMG1312-B30B** which is giving me same speeds 50 on cable and 25 on WiFi.

Please help.

Thanks :)

Comment: To be fair, wireless is ALWAYS slower than wired. If you care about connection speed, quality, and reliability, don't use wireless.

Comment: I'm not it's for the girlfriend haha :D

Comment: You forgot to mention the Wi-Fi details of your wireless client device. It would also help to know what RSSI (in negative dBm) your client gets from the AP, and what the AP reports as its transmit rate to that client.

Comment: if by client you mean the device, I'm testing on MacBook Pro, ThinkPad T450, iPhone 6s and iPhone 7. Channel width is set to 20/40 on both main router and AP. Channel is set to 10 on main router and 13 on the AP, these are not used by other networks around me. RSSI, I'm not there right now but I was literally 10cm from the router. I can check that tomorrow if needed. Not sure what you mean "what AP reports" but if you clarify I can find out. A person suggested it might be a Half Duplex issue which means half speed and do I get 22mbps for download BUT 38mbps for upload which is more

Answer (score -1):

25Mbit WiFi from 50Mbit doesn't sound unreasonably.

I've never seen a WiFi that delivered the stated numbers, it has to do with noise and all kinds of things.

As an example, I get 60Mbit on my Galaxy S7 from a WiFi spot that's located next to me that is supposed to be able to deliver 100Mbit, and the ISP delivers 100Mbit that I'm able to get on a wired connection.

 And the phone only senses that WiFi with full strength and one other WiFi with low strength.

Comment: since I do get roughly 50mbps from my main router via WiFi I would expect the same from the AP

Comment: Wi-Fi has more overhead than Ethernet, but it's not magic, and reasonable expectations can be reliably calculated once you know how.